# How to make an overlay div cover the div underneath entirely?

Tags: html, css, colors, overlay

I'm not a web designer but I taught myself basic CSS and HTML codes to make some adjustments to my website (and I enjoy experimenting). Sometimes there are things that just don't want to work.

This is one of those things.

I'm currently using a web builder plugin in Wordpress and building a coming soon page. I noticed that I can't do a color overlay in the web builder itself so I tried to do that in CSS.

The overlay div is visible. However, it doesn't cover the div underneath entirely.

What I exactly want is that the background image of the div is entirely covered by a color overlay div. But everything else like the text and buttons must be visible above the overlay div.

You can find the HTML and CSS code below. The link to the coming soon page is https://languagelearningmindset.com/coming-soon/ (it's not finished yet!)

Could you take a look at the page and the code and tell me which I can use and briefly explain why this didn't work?

Kamila

```css
div.vc_row.wpb_row.vc_row-fluid.headerCS.vc_custom_1528536749277.vc_row-has-fill.vc_row-no-padding.vc_row-o-full-height.vc_row-o-columns-middle.vc_row-o-equal-height.vc_row-flex {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.headerCS { 
  background-color: #000 !important;
  opacity: 0.8;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%; 
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
[vc_row][vc_column][vc_column_text]
<div class="headerCS">

[/vc_column_text][/vc_column][/vc_row][vc_row full_width="stretch_row_content_no_spaces" full_height="yes" equal_height="yes" css=".vc_custom_1528537770394{background: rgba(53,53,53,0.8) url(https://languagelearningmindset.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/desk-girl-hair-6384.jpg?id=36) !important;background-position: center !important;background-repeat: no-repeat !important;background-size: cover !important;*background-color: rgb(53,53,53) !important;}" el_class="headerCS"][vc_column css=".vc_custom_1528536650667{background-position: center !important;background-repeat: no-repeat !important;background-size: cover !important;}"][cz_gap height="30px" id="cz_20709"][cz_gap height="70px" id="cz_87042"][cz_gap height="70px" id="cz_40121"][vc_column_text]
<p style="text-align: center; font-size: 50px; color: #fff;"><strong>AWESOME STUFF COMING SOON</strong></p>
<p style="text-align: center; color: #fff;">We don't know when. Follow along and stay tuned.</p>
[/vc_column_text][cz_social_icons position="tac" id="cz_40817" social="%5B%7B%22icon%22%3A%22fa%20fa-instagram%22%2C%22title%22%3A%22Instagram%22%2C%22link%22%3A%22www.instagram.com%2Fkamilatekin%22%7D%2C%7B%22icon%22%3A%22fa%20fa-twitter%22%2C%22title%22%3A%22Twitter%22%2C%22link%22%3A%22www.twitter.com%2Fkamilatekin%22%7D%5D" sk_con="background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.01);" cz_social_icons="" sk_icons="font-size:25px;color:#ffffff;text-align:center;" sk_hover="color:#ffbb00;background-color:rgba(255,187,0,0.01);"][cz_gap height="120px" id="cz_52274" height_mobile="40px"][/vc_column][/vc_row][vc_row][vc_column][/vc_column][/vc_row]

</div>
```

Comment: The buttons and such are in the bottom div, and you want them to appear over top of the overlay?

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply `position:absolute` to the div you want to have background covering full viewport. Try this code.

```
#nifty-full-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```